# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '*'

Tags: php, syntax, syntax-error, exponentiation

My code:

```
<?php

    function ci($principle, $rate, $time) {

        $ci = ($principle * (( (1 + $rate / 100) ** $time) - 1));
        echo $ci;

    }

?>
<?php
    echo ci(10,10,10);
?>
```

And when I am running it, it gives the following error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '*' in D:\Xampp\htdocs\php\functions.php on line 4

Please tell me what's the error in line 4 (`$ci = ($principle * (((1+$rate/100)**$time)-1));`) ?

Comment: Is it intentional with the double `*` in  `)**$time)`  ?

Comment: it's a global issue raised by you as political mean as 'PHP' is specially not giving correct answer to you..read how to ask question on SO

Comment: FYI: You don't return anything in your function, so the echo call for the return value is unnecessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your syntax as it is, is correct. The problem is your PHP version. The [**`**`**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) operator was introduced in PHP 5.6 and you probably have something below.

So either update your PHP or use [`pow()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pow.php).

Comment: You always beat me by one +1

Comment: thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

OP had an extra `*` over

```
(1 + $rate / 100) ** $time)
```

which results into PHP syntax error Unexpected `*`
within PHP verison < 5.6.0 and works fine for the higher versions

```
function ci($principle, $rate, $time) {
    $ci = ($principle * (((1 + $rate / 100) * $time) - 1));
                                         //^^ removed extra *
    echo $ci;
}

ci(10, 10, 10);
```

[**Demo**](https://3v4l.org/VFHZd)

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more your answer?

Comment: Updated answer @Amarnasan